# kill remote process

Tags: vb.net, process, wmi

I used the below link and was able to set it up successfully:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26817/Killing-Processes-from-a-Visual-Basic-Application?msg=4868229#xx4868229xx

I am trying to figure out how to view/kill processes for a remote workstation in VB.NET versus locally?  Any ideas?

I've been testing with WMI but cant seem to figure it out and get it working.

Here is my class code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub endprocess(ByVal RemotePC As String, ByVal process As String)
        Dim objWMIService As Object
        Dim colProcessList As Array
        Dim objprocess As Object
        Dim response As Boolean
        Dim pcname As String = tbRemoteIP.Text

        objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & pcname & "\root\cimv2")
        process = "'" & process & "'"
        colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & "SDM Offline Tool")
        For Each objprocess In colProcessList
            response = MsgBox("End " & process & " on " & pcname & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel)
            If response = vbYes Then
                objprocess.Terminate()
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

I call the above with the below button:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    endprocess("pcname", "SDM Offline Tool")
End Sub
```

I'm getting a CAST error when i tried and end the SDM Offline Tool process on the remotepc (pcname)

Comment: Here is an example for WMI: http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/remoting/19019-remotely-ending-process.html

Comment: Yea i saw that:
but how do i call that?  Or do i place that code inside of a button?

Comment: Paste this code into your form class, then in your button handler call `endprocess("RemotePC", "process")`.

Comment: I updated my code, can you take a look, im still having issues.

Comment: My first guess is that "SDM Offline Tool" is not the name of your process. Try with "notepad" first.

Comment: Another thing - you forgot single quotes in the WMI query, around the process name.

Comment: it is the name of the process, i am able to kill it local via taskmgr

Comment: colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & 'SDM Offline Tool')

Like that?

Comment: No, like this: "Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & "SDM Offline Tool" & "'"

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it worked for me with "notepad.exe":

```
Public Sub endprocess(ipAddress As String, processName As String)
  Dim scope As New ManagementScope("\\" & ipAddress & "\root\cimv2")
  Dim query As New SelectQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" & processName & "'")

  Using searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query)
    Dim queryCollection As ManagementObjectCollection = searcher.[Get]()
    For Each process As ManagementObject In queryCollection
      process.InvokeMethod("Terminate", Nothing)
    Next
  End Using
End Sub

Sub Main()
  endprocess("ipAddress", "notepad.exe")
End Sub
```

Don't forget to add reference to `System.Management` (.NET 4.0), and add `Imports` at the top.