# Kill application running on server (from client side)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, web-applications, kill-process

I'm using VB.NET to develop a web app that can execute some .exe files (created by me) that will run on the server and continue running until the end of the operation.

Occasionally, the exe file becomes "stuck" and I can't do anything but kill it from the Task Manager on the server.

The thing is, before executing another exe file, I check if there is one already running and I prevent a possible "double" execution of the same program so users can end up waiting for a very long time.

I use this to run the exe:

```
ProgrammaDaEseguire = Server.MapPath("/Batch") & "\my_program.exe"

Public Function RunSchedulatore(ByVal ProgrammaDaEseguire As String,
                                ByVal IdSchedulatore As Integer) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim Proc As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        Proc.StartInfo.FileName = ProgrammaDaEseguire
        Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = IdSchedulatore 
        Proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

        Proc.Start() 


        RunSchedulatore = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        writeLog
        RunSchedulatore = False
    End Try

End Function
```

Is there any way I can kill this process that is running on the server?

I'm able to kill the process running on my client, but I'm not sure I can kill the process on the server side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kill remote process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941139/kill-remote-process)

Comment: Create another program, or batch that will kill the proccess? `TASKKILL` would do the trick